# How to display multiple values with same ID php

Tags: php, html

I am creating profile of our users and I want to display their children details. Users data is stored in one table and their children data is stored in other.
For one userid there is more than one children detail.
Now, I want to display different children details with same userid (userid is muraqebeenID in children table).
How can I do that?

My DB look like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
|     ID      |muraqebeenId | childName       |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
|      1      |     1       | John Doe        |
+-------------+-------------------------------|
|      2      |     1       | Jane Doe        |
+-------------|-------------|-----------------+
```

Here's my code:

````
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body >

<?php
//connect to DB
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "idaramsb_newidara");

if ($con-> connect_error)
{
    die("Connection Failed". $con-> connect_error);
}   

//set page no.

if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
    $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
} else {
    $pageno = 1;
}

//
$schools="";
if (isset($_GET['schoolId'])) {
    $schools = "and tblusers.schoolId=".$_GET['schoolId'];
 } 

 $no_of_records_per_page = 5;
 if (isset($_GET['records'])) {
  $no_of_records_per_page = $_GET['records'];  
 }

$offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;


$sql1="SELECT count(tblusers.userid) as total FROM tblusers
left JOIN tblschools on tblusers.schoolId=tblschools.schoolId
left JOIN jameastd on tblusers.jameaSanad=jameastd.jameasnd
where tblusers.status = 1 ".$schools." and tblusers.liveUser=1 and (tblusers.roleid = 3 or tblusers.roleid = 4 or tblusers.roleid = 17 or tblusers.roleid = 23 or tblusers.roleid = 27 or tblusers.roleid = 24)";

$totalp = 0;

$sql="SELECT tblschools.schoolId, tblschools.schoolName as scnm, jameastd.jameastd, YEAR(tblusers.dobGregorian) as dobGregoria, tblmuraqebeenswot.*, tblroles.roleid, tblroles.name, tblmuraqebeenchildrendetails.*, tblmuraqebeenspousedetails.*, tblusers.* FROM tblusers 
left JOIN tblschools on tblusers.schoolId=tblschools.schoolId
left JOIN jameastd on tblusers.jameaSanad=jameastd.jameasnd
left join tblmuraqebeenswot on tblmuraqebeenswot.muraqebeenId=tblusers.userid
left join tblroles on tblroles.roleid=tblusers.roleId
LEFT JOIN tblmuraqebeenspousedetails on tblusers.userid=tblmuraqebeenspousedetails.muraqebeenId
left JOIN tblmuraqebeenchildrendetails on tblusers.userid=tblmuraqebeenchildrendetails.muraqebeenId
where tblusers.liveUser=1 and tblusers.status=1 and (tblusers.roleid = 3 or tblusers.roleid = 4 or tblusers.roleid = 17 or tblusers.roleid = 23 or tblusers.roleid = 27 or tblusers.roleid = 24) GROUP BY tblusers.userid ORDER by tblusers.roleid  LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";



$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

$resultcheck=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$no_of_pages = ceil($totalp / $no_of_records_per_page);
$date = date('Y');

    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $totalp = $rows['total'];   
    }


while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $roq=$rows['dobGregoria'];
    $age=$date - $roq;


echo "
<table border=1 class=headings id=content>
<tr>
<td colspan=3><span class=bold>Name: </span>".$rows['fullName']."</td>
<td width=200px><span class=bold>ITS ID: </span>".$rows['itsId']."</td>
<td rowspan=5 align=center width=160px><img width=140px src=https://www.idaramsb.net/newidara/assets/img/itsphoto.php?itsid=".$rows['itsId']."></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width=220px><span class=bold>Mauze: </span>".$rows['scnm']."</td>
<td width=><span class=bold>Muddat: </span></td>
<td><span class=bold>Age: </span>".$age."</td>
<td><span class=bold>Vatan: </span>".$rows['vatan']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan=><span class=bold>Taqarrur Year: </span>".$rows['taqarrurYear']."</td>
<td width=230px><span class=bold>Mobile No.: </span>".$rows['mobile']."</td>
<td colspan=2><span class=bold>Email: </span>".$rows['email']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span class=bold>Jamea Farigh Year: </span>".$rows['farighYear']."</td>
<td><span class=bold>Designation: </span>".$rows['name']."</td>
<td colspan=2><span class=bold>Jamea Sanad: </span>".$rows['jameaSanad']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan=2><span class=bold>Qualification: </span>".$rows['education']."</td>
<td colspan=2><span class=bold>Hifz: </span>".$rows['hifzTill']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan=5 height=50px><span class=bold>Past Mawaze:</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan=2 valign=top height=300px><span class=bold>STRENGTHS</span><br>".$rows['strength']."</td>
<td colspan=3 valign=top><span class=bold>WEAKNESSES</span><br>".$rows['weakness']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2 valign=top height=300px><span class=bold>OPPURTUNITIES</span><br>".$rows['opportunities']."</td>
<td colspan=3 valign=top><span class=bold>THREATS</span><br>".$rows['threats']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=5 align=center valign=top height=200px>
<span class=bold>Family Details</span>

<table height= width=1000px border=1>
<tr>
<td width=500px height=10px style='border-top:0.5px dotted;' align=center colspan=2>
<span class=top>Spouse Details</span><br>
</td>
<td width=500px style='border-left:0.5px dotted; border-top:0.5px dotted;'>
<div class=top>Children Details</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
Name: ".$rows['spouseName']."
</td>
<td colspan=2>
Name: ".$rows['childName']."
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
ITS ID: ".$rows['ejamatNo']."
</td>
<td>
Teaching in MSB?: ".$rows['teachinginMsb']."
</td>
<td>
ITS ID: ".$rows['ejamatNo']."
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
Qualification: ".$rows['qualification']."
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
Computer Skills: ".$rows['computerLiteracy']."
</td>
</tr>

</tr>
</table>

</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=5 align=center height= ><span class=bold>Personality Traits</span>
<iframe height=689px width=100% src=http://139.59.31.87/horizons/presults.php?itsid=".$rows['itsId']."&testid=1&sw> </iframe> 
</td> 
</tr>

</table> 
<br>";
}

?>




</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this helps:

```
SELECT * FROM `childTable` WHERE `muraqebeenId` = 1;
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the quick response. I tried doing that but I want to display multiple children details for one ID.

Comment: @HussainKhhave you tried to run the query? it should return row(s) with 'muraqebeenId' 1